# How to manually check Ubuntu version? (e.g. from hard drive)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, version

There is a fast way to check ubuntu version of the system:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 11.10
Release:        11.10
Codename:       oneiric
```

But what are the files that store this information and how can I access them? Particularly, I've got an old partition with a dead Linux lying there and I would like to check what was its Ubuntu version. `lsb_release -a` shows my current Linux version only...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `/etc/lsb-release` for that:

```
~$ cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=13.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=raring
```

Comment: Note that this answer is also valid for other distributions. [/etc/lsb-release](http://linux.die.net/man/1/lsb_release) is common to several of the large distributions.

Answer (score 5):

You can try chrooting into that system from another Linux or LiveCD. Let's assume your dead distro is on `sda2`. First, mount the partition:

```
$ mount /dev/sda2 /mnt
```

Now bind folders with crucial binaries to replace possibly dead ones. `mount -B` mounts one directory over the other one virtually replacing its contents, but without physically touching it:

```
$ mount -B /bin /mnt/bin
$ mount -B /sbin /mnt/sbin
$ mount -B /usr/bin /mnt/usr/bin
```

Now `chroot` to the old distro. `chroot` will pretend that given directory is `/` (so in our case we'll have a shell running in an offline distro, working on its files except for binaries we've bound before)

```
$ chroot /mnt
```

Now any command you issue will work as if that partition is your filesystem root. `lsb_release -a` will be executed from your binaries, but will read from files of the dead distro.

You can use `chroot` for many other things. For example you can upgrade Ubuntu without booting it: just boot a LiveCD, mount Ubuntu's partition, bind crucial directories like `/proc` etc. (do NOT binaries - this would update LiveCD binaries) and run `do-release-upgrade` in the chrooted shell.

Comment: This becomes a lot more complex if the other system is of a different architecture, or even a different operating system. While it provides useful information, there are drawbacks to this approach. (And you forgot libraries, which will need to be bind-mounted into the chroot jail as well.)

Answer (score 1):

Does the following warrant a re-examination of the original poser's problem for a viable solution (which is required for salvage operations)?

Unfortunately, the accepted answer to the OP does not provide the correct result.

The volume OS information extracted as follows:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:/media/ubuntu/Boot18.04$ cat etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=12.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=precise
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 12.04 LTS"

ubuntu@ubuntu:/media/ubuntu/Boot18.04$ cat etc/os-release
cat: etc/os-release: No such file or directory

ubuntu@ubuntu:/media/ubuntu/Boot18.04$ cat '/media/ubuntu/Boot18.04/etc/issue' 
Ubuntu 12.04 LTS \n \l

ubuntu@ubuntu:/media/ubuntu/Boot18.04$ cat '/media/ubuntu/Boot18.04/etc/issue.net' 
Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
```

is inconsistent with the actual boot version which was definitely 18.04."something" .  Is it possible to definitively determine the actual installed version *easily*? (especially given that said volume no longer boots)

(It is of course possible to install each of several OS versions and then compare binaries ... !)

The 18.04."something" volume above definitely booted but *not* 12.04 though it *was* created using a 12.04 boot volume.

To be clear, the operational 18.04.1 bootable volume that was used when extracting the information above *is* consistently identifiable via:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="18.04.1 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS"
VERSION_ID="18.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=bionic
UBUNTU_CODENAME=bionic

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=18.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=bionic
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS"

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS \n \l

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ cat /etc/issue.net
Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
```

Comment: OPs question was asked more than 6 years ago. Things change, this does not invalidate the question and answers given back then, it does mean that someone getting similar symptoms on newer software may need to post their own question rather than trying to use this one.

Answer (score -2):

Open the Terminal (keyboard shortcut: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>)

Enter the command

```
lsb_release -a
```

Your version will be shown on the Description line.

Comment: The OP specifically asked another way of checking than the solution you mentioned.